# number of DAGs in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Q1. Given an undirected and connected graph, $G=(V,E)$, what is the number of directed Acyclic Graphs (DAGs) that can be constructed? I cannot remove any edge.

DAG is a directed graph with no cycle.

Q.2 Can anyone suggest the minimum number of topological orders (or an algorithm which generates them) to construct all DAGs.